# How to click a button in a specific row in Playwright?

Tags: typescript, automated-tests, playwright

I'm writing a test in Playwright and TypeScript.
I have two rows, and in both the same button, expanding the row, the button class in both is the same:
"<button class="ant-table-row-expand-icon>"
I click the button with this:

```
await page.click(".ant-table-row-expand-icon")
```

I want to click only in one specific row on this button to expand the row
rows are added randomly each time the tests are run
rows are mapped as "rowId"
The problem is that after one start I click on the button in the right line, and when I run it again in the button in the second line
I don't know how to change it so that it clicks the button in the right row every time?

change it so that it clicks the button in the right row every time?

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the html code of the table/buttons? If there are two buttons with the same id, I find it weird that your code is running, playwright usually returns error when more than one locator is found.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because in your scenario once the button is clicked, it must be changing class properties in some way and next test clicks on the second row as now that becomes the first row with the given class property.

> Always start an test with `stable base state like home page to ensure consistent behavior.`

On having every test starting from same known base state, it will not find an already expanded row(mutated state) from previous test.